# The set $X$ can be seen as index set?

Tags: notation, set-theory, index-notation

Let $X$ be a set, and the power set of $X$ be $\mathcal P(X).$

For $\mathcal B \subset \color{red}{\mathcal P(X)},$
does
\begin{align}
&\quad \ \left\{ U\subset X \mid \exists \Lambda : \mathrm{index \ set}, \exists \{U_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}\subset \mathcal B\ \ ;\ U=\cup_{\lambda\in \Lambda} U_\lambda\right\}\\
&=\{ U\subset X \mid \forall x\in U, \exists B\in \mathcal B \ ; \ x\in B \subset U \}
\end{align} hold ?

I expect it holds. I proved LHS$\subset $RHS, but I'm not sure my proof of LHS$\supset $RHS is correct.

---

My proof.

Let $U\in $ RHS.

Then, $\forall x\in U, \exists B_x \in \mathcal B \ ; \ x\in B_x  \subset U $ holds.

Each $B_x$ belongs to $\mathcal B$ i.e., $\{ B_x \}_{x\in \color{red}U}\subset \mathcal B$, and $U=\cup_{x\in \color{red} U} B_x$ holds, so $U\in $LHS.

---

I'm not sure this is correct, since I don't know whether we can see $\color{red}U$ as index set.

$\color{red} U$ is defined as a **set**, but can we see $\color{red} U$ as an index set ?

Comment: Maybe someone else will be able to understand your notation better than I do, but why do you use $B$ for both $\mathcal{B} \subset B$, and as the bound variable in $\exists B \in \mathcal{B}$? Are they related? If not, then $B$ doesn't show up anywhere else, so why even write $\mathcal{B} \subset B$?

Comment: I mistyped. I edited. @Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any set can be used as an index set. Index sets are not special types of sets, they're just ordinary sets that are being used in a special way: to index a family of other sets.

That said, your proof is not quite right, because you have defined a set $B_x$ for every $x\in U$, not for every $x\in X$. So your index set should be $U$, not $X$.

Comment: Exact answer. Thank you. @Alex_Kruckman